# Why do I get a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError for com.sun.webkit.dom.HTMLInputElementImpl.clickImpl(J)V on Ubuntu 14.04.5

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, javafx, unsatisfiedlinkerror

For some reason I get this execption

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" io.webfolder.ui4j.api.util.Ui4jException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError  com.sun.webkit.dom.HTMLInputElementImpl.clickImpl(J)V
    at io.webfolder.ui4j.webkit.aspect.WebKitAspect$CallableExecutor.run(WebKitAspect.java:41)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.webkit.dom.HTMLInputElementImpl.clickImpl(J)V
    at com.sun.webkit.dom.HTMLInputElementImpl.clickImpl(Native Method)
    at com.sun.webkit.dom.HTMLInputElementImpl.click(HTMLInputElementImpl.java:506)
    at io.webfolder.ui4j.webkit.dom.WebKitElement.click_aroundBody50(WebKitElement.java:299)
    at io.webfolder.ui4j.webkit.dom.WebKitElement$AjcClosure51.run(WebKitElement.java:1)
    at io.webfolder.ui4j.internal.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
    at io.webfolder.ui4j.webkit.aspect.WebKitAspect$CallableExecutor.run(WebKitAspect.java:39)
    ... 6 more
```

My system is

```
~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

And my JAVA version is

```
:~# java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

And if I run the nm command on the so-lib I seem to think that the function is there

```
:~# nm /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/i386/libjfxwebkit.so | grep HTMLInputElementImpl | grep clickImpl
010254b0 t Java_com_sun_webkit_dom_HTMLInputElementImpl_clickImpl
```

What is it that I am missing in all of this ?

I have tried numerous times to reinstall Java, but that did not help.

Comment: I'm facing this too. jdk1.8.0_172,  jdk1.8.0_162, jdk1.8.0_161, jdk-10.0.1, jdk-9.0.4. No one work.

Comment: I get the same issue on the mac.  Seems like an incomplete implementation.  Would love to hear any updates if you've found the cause!

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue on macOS. One workaround is to check if the node/element is a HTMLInputElement with type==submit and in those cases invoke .getForm().submit().

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue in JDK-14 and JFX-14. My workaround is to use webEngine.executeScript instead because getForm() returns null for my use case.